# У меня получилась функция которая работает быстрее чем pandas, так ли это?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Задание заключается в том чтобы найти разницу значений по модулю между двумя столбцами и где она больше то и вывести. Есть файл olympics.csv, там два поля gold и gold1. Находишь разницу и выводишь

И вывел время, делал в jupyter notebook

В случае `pandas` сделал однострочный вариант

```
def func():
    return (df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']).idxmax()

CPU times: user 4.56 ms, sys: 136 µs, total: 4.7 ms
Wall time: 4.09 ms
```

И сделал тоже самое только через цикл

```
def func1( arr, arr1 ):
    sum = 0
    ind = 0
    t = 0
    for i,v in zip(arr, arr1) :
        if abs(i - v) > sum : 
            sum = i
            ind = t
        t += 1
    return df.index[ind]

CPU times: user 263 µs, sys: 63 µs, total: 326 µs
Wall time: 333 µs
```

Это в 14 раз быстрее, хотя гениального в коде у меня ничего нету

Правильно ли я использую pandas или он медленный, или же он медленный только для этого случая?)

Comment: Это вполне нормально если у вас крошечный DataFrame. А вот если у вас 100.000+ строк и цикл работает быстрее то я бы сильно удивился...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте увеличить ваш DataFrame в 1000 - 100000 раз и повторите ваш тест.

резервная копия оригинального DF:

```
sav = df.copy()
```

увеличиваем в 10.000 раз:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)
```

здесь повтор ваших тестов...

**Пример:**

```
def func():
    return (df.a - df.b).abs().idxmax()

# func1( arr, arr1 ) - я взял из вашего кода без изменений
```

Тестовый DataFrame:

```
In [29]: np.random.seed(0)

In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(30,2), columns=['a','b'])

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
           a         b
0   0.548814  0.715189
1   0.602763  0.544883
2   0.423655  0.645894
3   0.437587  0.891773
4   0.963663  0.383442
..       ...       ...
25  0.570197  0.438602
26  0.988374  0.102045
27  0.208877  0.161310
28  0.653108  0.253292
29  0.466311  0.244426

[30 rows x 2 columns]

In [32]: df.shape
Out[32]: (30, 2)
```

Timing:

```
In [32]: df.shape
Out[32]: (30, 2)

In [33]: %timeit func()
265 µs ± 2.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [34]: %timeit func1(df.a, df.b)
53.5 µs ± 161 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

увеличим DF в 10.000 раз:

```
In [35]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [36]: df.shape
Out[36]: (300000, 2)

In [37]: %timeit func()
3.65 ms ± 6.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit func1(df.a, df.b)
76.8 ms ± 1.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

увеличим еще в 10 раз:

```
In [39]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10, ignore_index=True)

In [40]: df.shape
Out[40]: (3000000, 2)

In [41]: %timeit func()
37 ms ± 2.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit func1(df.a, df.b)
780 ms ± 25.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```